# Is there a difference between 'doot' (दूत) and 'dut' (दुत) in Sanskrit?

Tags: grammar, sanskrit

I recently came across a [verse](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01163.htm) from RigVeda

```
यदक्रन्दः परथमं जायमान उद्यन समुद्रादुत वा पुरीषात | 
शयेनस्य पक्षा हरिणस्य बाहू उपस्तुत्यं महि जातं ते अर्वन ||
```

Now, I can understand `उद्यन समुद्रादुत` (in other versions, its `उदयन्त समुद्रादुत`) as meaning '**arisen from the sea**' but I can't make sense of the ending `दुत`.

1. What does `दुत` mean ?
2. Does it have any relationship with `दूत` (messenger) ?

Comment: ok.. cross-posting it there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before understanding the mantra, we need to break it down into individual words. It is not an easy task to understand the words used in a vedic mantra even after breaking it down into words. If my memory serves me right, the separate words in the first mantra are:

> यदक्रन्दः प्रथमम् जायमानः उद्यन् समुद्रात् उत वा पुरीषात्

Note that there's special sandhi happening between the words `उद्यन्` and `समुद्रात्` Through the application of a few Panini rules, the augment `त्` appears at the beginning of समुद्रात् There are no two version of the mantra. When sandhi is performed (and it always is while chanting the mantra), the additional `त्` is heard. Publishers of the text may sometimes skip the sandhi, causing one to incorrectly presume that there are two versions of the text.

I'm doubtful whether the first word is a compound or should be be shown as

> यत् अक्रन्दः

Only a commentary on the mantra can resolve this ambiguity.

The word `उत` is an indeclinable (also called `अव्ययम्` in sanskrit). It is used in many meanings, one being in the sense of raising a question. Hence there's no possibility of the word `दूत` appearing in the mantra. There's some kind of sandhi happening at `समुद्रात् उत`- the trailing त् at the end of a word is replaced with a `द्` This must've caused the confusion.

From Apte's dictionary:

http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.1:1:3075.apte

> उत ind. 1 A particle expressing (a) doubt, uncer- tainty, guess (or);
>   तत्किमयमातपदोषः स्यादुत यथा मे मनसि वर्तते Ś.3; स्थाणुरयमुत पुरुषः G.
>   M. वीरो रसः किमयमित्युत दर्प एषः Veeracharitam. (b) alternative;
>   usually a correla- tive of किं (whether, or); किमिदं गुरुभिरुपदिष्टमुत
>   धर्मशास्त्रेषु पठितमुत मोक्षप्राप्तियुक्तिरियम् K.155; किं येन सृजसि
>   व्यक्तमुत येन बिभर्षि तत् Ku.6.23; the place of उत is also taken by
>   आहो or आहोस्वित्; sometimes आहो, आहोस्वित् or स्वित् are joined to उत.
>   (c) association, connection, (having a cumulative force, 'and',
>   'also'); उत बलवानुताबलः; (d) interrogation; उत दण्डः पतिष्यति; (e)
>   deliberation; (f) intensity; (g) wishing (especially at the beginning
>   of a sentence followed by a potential 'would that'); (h) some- times
>   used as an expletive; (i) oft. used for the sake of emphasis
>   especially at the end of a line after इति or a verb; तदा
>   विद्याद्विवृद्धं सत्त्वमित्युत Bg.14.11; धर्मे नष्टे कुलं
>   कृत्स्नमधर्मो$भिभवत्युत 1.4. -2 With a preceding प्रति = on the
>   contrary, on the other hand; but; सामवादाः सकोपस्य तस्य प्रत्युत
>   दीपकाः Śi.2.55; न केवलं ध्रियते प्रत्युत पर्युपास्यमानस्तिष्ठति Nāg.5.
>   -3 With a preceding किं = how much more or how much less; see किम्. उत, -उत Either-or; एकमेव वरं पुंसामुत राज्यमुताश्रमः G. M. उत वा or
>   else, and; वा-उतवा, उताहोवा पि-वा either-or; -आहो, -आहोस्वित् Used for
>   the sake of emphasis; उताहो हत- वीर्यास्ते बभूवुः पृथिवीक्षितः
>   Rām.7.31.4. शालिहोत्रः किं नु स्याद् उताहोस्विद् राजा नलः.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please mention the sandhi rule by which समुद्रात् उत is becoming समुद्रादुत, or an example for it ? I've tried to find several versions of this mantra, but I never get समुद्रात् उत in any of them. If possible, please provide a reference for the same.

Comment: Sure the rule is झलां जशोऽन्ते (Panini sutra no. 8-2-39) - The letter `झल्` at the end of a word is replaced by a जश् The letter `त्` belongs to the `झल्` group and the corresponding `जश्` letter for it would be `द्` This rule is applied without exception in all places. Some examples `ककुभ् अस्ति` => `ककुप् अस्ति`, `जलमुच् आस्ते` => `जलमुज् आस्ते`, `ग्रामात् बहिः गच्छति` => `ग्रामाद् बहिः गच्छति`

Comment: Awesome.. thanks a lot :) I found some good examples for it here too : https://tinyurl.com/lmzgxgz

Comment: You can look through the posts on http://avg-sanskrit.org for examples as well.

Comment: Thanks.. Its a little off-topic, but can you help me locate एतम् in any online dictionary. I know it means "this", but for some reason, I can't find it in any online dictionary. Have tried Apte's dictionary above, and also here : http://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/sanskrit/index.php

Comment: `एतम्` is the accusative singular of the word `एतत्` in masculine. Since it only signifies the number, gender and case of the nominal stem `एतत्` you won't find it in the dictionary. A dictionary will only have entries for the nominal stem and possibly, the nominative singular for all words. For e.g.`एष गच्छति` translates to This (person) goes. `राम एतं वदति` translates to `Rama speaks to this (person)` Please refer to sabda manjari to see the declensions of words in all genders and also pronouns. https://ia800200.us.archive.org/3/items/SabdaManjari/SabdaManjari.djvu